# Excel: how to count based on 2 conditions if second condition can appear in multiple columns?

Tags: excel, count, conditional-statements

[image]

If I have the data as shown in the image and I  would want to count how often a appears in any column if column A contains "id1", how would I do that?

I tried countifs(A:A, "id1", B:M, "a") but that does not work. Does anyone have a solution to this? Adding extra helper columns which contain the count of a, b or c per row won't work because in my actual data there are many more possibilities.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A12="id1")*(B2:M12="a"))`.

Comment: To add to @BigBen's answer, I would use named ranges (A2:A12 named ID, B2:M12 named TIMES) and use =sumproduct((ID="id1")*(TIMES="a"))